# Applying conditional after nested loop to the parent loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, nested-loops

I have this code:

```
values="2"
content=["line1","line2","line3"]
for line in content:
    if values not in line:
        print(line)
```

which successfully prints out items of `content` when value `2` is not in those items:

```
line1
line3
```

Practically, I am grabbing `content` out of a file.readlines() method.

Now, I am stuck when I have to compare more than one value against each of the content lines:

```
values=["2","3"]
```

Again, I need to check if `2` or `3` are in each of the `content` lines and print the line when they are not.

I came up with this:

```
values=["2","3"]
content=["line1","line2","line3"]
for line in content:
    for value in values:
        if value not in line:
            print(line)
```

But that would normally return this:

```
line1
line1
line2
line3
```

I would expect only `line1` to be printed out.
Any workaround to this?

Comment: can't you use something like `if not any(vv in line for vv in values)`?

Comment: Shouldn't `items` be `values`?

Comment: Yes, it should. Edited the question to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable that you set in the nested loop, and check after the loop is done.

```
values=["2","3"]
content=["line1","line2","line3"]
for line in content:
    in_line = false
    for item in values:
        if item in line:
            in_line = true
            break
    if not in_line:
        print(line)
```

Or you can use the `any` function.

```
values=["2","3"]
content=["line1","line2","line3"]
for line in content:
    if not any(value in line for value in values):
        print(line)
```